# Bubbles chart: how to avoid bubbles being cut off? google visualization

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I'm using google visualization for bubble chart, data to x axis and Y axis is dynamic. I'm facing issue here is that bubbles get cut-off and there size is also not uniform.

using following options

```
options = {
                'title': 'Chart',
                'width': '100%',
                'height': 550,
                legend: {position: 'right'},
                vAxis: {
                        title: 'Score',
                    viewWindow: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 5
                    },

                    baselineColor: {
                       color: '#4c78c6', 
                    },
                    sizeAxis : {minValue: 0,  maxSize: 15},
                    ticks: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                },
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Years',
                    baselineColor: {
                       color: '#4c78c6', 
                    }
                },
                sizeAxis : {minValue: 0,  maxSize: 15},
                bubble: {
                    textStyle: {
                        color: 'none',
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    isHtml: true,
                },
                colors: colors,
                chartArea: { width: "30%", height: "50%" }
            };
```

**EDIT** data passed to

```
var rows = [
    ['ID','YEAR','SCORE', 'AVG1', 'AVG']
    ['Deka marc', 2.5, 5, '76-100%', 100]
    ['Max cala',  28.2,3.4,'76-100%', 77]
    ['shane root',4.2, 1, '0-25%', 0]
]
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows);
```

from above array I'm removing element 3 on hover as do not wish to show in tooltip. AVG1 column is for legend

getting o/p like this
[image]

Comment: using this option will set the bubbles to the same size, regardless of value in 5th column --> `sizeAxis : {minSize: 15,  maxSize: 15},` -- (note size vs value)

Comment: are you sure you have `minSize` and `maxSize`?  -- not `minValue` and `maxSize` as in the code above...

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var rangeX = data.getColumnRange(1);
```

to know the range of column
and then use

```
hAxis: {
  viewWindow: { 
            min: rangeX.min-10,
            max: rangeX.max+10
            }
       },
}
```

do similarly for yAxis

https://jsfiddle.net/geniusunil/nt4ymrLe/4/

Answer (score 0):

Add inside hAxis the viewWindow option.
This is a sample code:

```
viewWindow: { 
            min: 0,
            max: 40
            }
```

You can change max according your biggest value in your dataset you want to show. I mean if is 30 (as in your example) you can set max: 40, or if is 75 you can set max equal to 85.

JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zth0vnyk/).

Comment: The JSfiddle is not related specifically to your question. However, it was providing a solution for the above problem that could be used for all chart types.
 Now, because of your question, I edited the example using a bubble chart. 
Let me know if now is helpful to you.

Comment: The size of the bubble depends on the 5th column of the row of your rows variabile. I mean, in your dataset the column AVG. If you set to the same number for each dataset row you will have the same bubble size

Comment: thnaks i saw that in google doc too (Column 4 ). thanks will manage data accordingly

Answer (score 0):

to find the range of each axis dynamically, use data table method --> `getColumnRange`

then you can use the `ticks` option to increase the range.

```
var rangeX = data.getColumnRange(1);
var ticksX = [];
for (var i = (Math.floor(rangeX.min / 10) * 10); i <= (Math.ceil(rangeX.max / 10) * 10); i = i + 10) {
  ticksX.push(i);
}

var rangeY = data.getColumnRange(2);
var ticksY = [];
for (var i = Math.floor(rangeY.min) - 1; i <= Math.ceil(rangeY.max) + 1; i++) {
  ticksY.push(i);
}
```

to make the size of the bubble uniform, set `minSize` & `maxSize` to the same value.

```
sizeAxis : {minSize: 15,  maxSize: 15},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
    var rows = [
        ['ID','YEAR','SCORE', 'AVG1', 'AVG'],
        ['Deka marc', 2.5, 5, '76-100%', 100],
        ['Max cala',  28.2,3.4,'76-100%', 77],
        ['shane root',4.2, 1, '0-25%', 0]
    ];
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows);

    var rangeX = data.getColumnRange(1);
    var ticksX = [];
    for (var i = (Math.floor(rangeX.min / 10) * 10); i <= (Math.ceil(rangeX.max / 10) * 10); i = i + 10) {
      ticksX.push(i);
    }

    var rangeY = data.getColumnRange(2);
    var ticksY = [];
    for (var i = Math.floor(rangeY.min) - 1; i <= Math.ceil(rangeY.max) + 1; i++) {
      ticksY.push(i);
    }

    var options = {
          title: 'Chart',
          width: '100%',
          height: 550,
          legend: {position: 'right'},
          vAxis: {
              title: 'Score',
              baselineColor: {
                 color: '#4c78c6',
              },
              sizeAxis : {minSize: 15,  maxSize: 15},
              ticks: ticksY
          },
          hAxis: {
              title: 'Years',
              baselineColor: {
                 color: '#4c78c6',
              },
              ticks: ticksX
          },
          sizeAxis : {minSize: 10,  maxSize: 10},
          bubble: {
              textStyle: {
                  color: 'none',
              }
          },
          tooltip: {
              isHtml: true,
          },
          //colors: colors,
          chartArea: { width: "30%", height: "50%" }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 10% of the difference between the max and min

```
vAxis: {
         viewWindow: { 
            min: rangeY.min - ((+rangeY.max - rangeY.min) * 10 / 100),
            max: rangeY.max + ((+rangeY.max - rangeY.min) * 10 / 100)
            }
       },

hAxis: {
        viewWindow: { 
            min: rangeX.min - ((+rangeX.max - rangeX.min) * 10 / 100),
            max: rangeX.max + ((+rangeX.max - rangeX.min) * 10 / 100)
            }
       },
```